# Wireless card does not detect any wireless networks

Tags: wireless, dell

Its a Dell Latitude E6400, dual bot windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. Already tried out the "additional drivers" while being connected via Ethernet cable but none show up. Any other advices?

Comment: Please provide `sudo lshw` and `sudo lspci`.

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Latitude-E6400 too. I solved it installing the b43 proprietary driver with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Then reboot and connect to a wireless network